# Physical Interpretation of the Spectrum of MPS Transfer Matrices

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-entanglement, spin-chains, tensor-network

Take an injective, translation invariant MPS with transfer matrix $E = \sum_\sigma \overline{A^\sigma} \otimes A^\sigma$ (i am using the terminology of https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0410227 , eq. (6)).

Then (by injectivity), $E$ will have one eigenvalue $1$ and all other eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ have $|\lambda_i|<1$. This corresponds to exponential clustering of correlation functions, in particular, the smallest correlation length in the system is given by $1/\xi = - \log |\lambda|$, with $\lambda$ the second largest eigenvalue.

The point is that thus this part of the spectrum of $E$ has direct physical meaning: given a state with a given correlation length, we know that we should use a MPS with some given gap between the first and the second largest eigenvalue.

From there i would be interested if there is more information with direct physical interpretation in the spectrum of $E$. I will state my problem with decreasing generality:

1. Assume $|\lambda_1| \leq |\lambda_2| \leq \cdots$ is the spectrum of $|E|$, and assume we have a matrix product state of large bond dimension with a given correlation length, gap above the ground state, Renyi entropy etc. Can we say sth about the decay properties of $|\lambda_n|$?
2. More explicitely i am wondering if it is possible to find an $N$ depending only on a "thermodynamic" quantities (like correlation lengths, energy gaps etc.) s.t.
   $$ \sum_{n > N} |\lambda_n| < 1 \ .$$
3. I want to do this for the following reason: given an injective matrix product state $\rho$ on a subsystem $X$, it holds that $$ \lim_{X \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}} \text{Tr}(\rho_X^2) = C = \text{const.}$$
   Is it possible to quantify how fast this limit is approached, again in terms of correlation lengths, gaps etc? i.e. can one find some decaying function $f(x) > 0$ s.t. 
   $$ |\text{Tr}(\rho_X^2) - C | \leq f(|X|) \ ,$$ 
   where the form of $f$ depends on properties of the state alone (and not the tensor network chosen to represent it)?

I can get more explicit on the last point. Assume the MPS has bond dimension $D$ and correlation length $\xi_D$, then:

$$ |\text{Tr}(\rho_X^2) - C | \leq D e^{-|X|/\xi_D} \ , \quad (1) $$

but this explicitely depends on the bond dimension of the chosen matrix product representation.

EDIT: I have a sketchy idea of what i want to do... so here is said sketch.

I interpret the results of this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0505140 as: Given a state $\psi$ satisfying an area law for the Renyi-entropy $S_t$ for some $t < 1$, i can find a translation invariant MPS state $\psi_D$ which approximates $\psi$ on any subset.  Denote the reduced density matrices to a subset $X:=\{1,2,\cdots L\}$ by

$$ \rho_L := \text{Tr}_{X^c}(|\psi\rangle \langle \psi|) \ , \quad \rho_{L,D} := \text{Tr}_{X^c}(|\psi_D\rangle \langle \psi_D|) \ .$$

Then the statement is that there are $r \in (1, \infty)$ and constants $C(r,\psi)$ such that

$$ \| \rho_L - \rho_{L,D} \|_1 := \text{Tr}| \rho_L - \rho_{L,D} | \leq C(r,\psi) L^2 D^{-r} \ . \quad (2) $$

I think this should be true; in the paper i mention this is similar to equation (5), only that there only the case $L=2$ is considered. In any case, by blocking, i can reduce the general $L$ case to the $L=2$ case, and that gives the $L^2$ dependence on the r.h.s. of the above equation. Then furthermore i used the estimate of Lemma 2 to upper bound what in the paper is called $\epsilon(D)$, and i just assume that by choosing some appropriate prefactors the r.h.s. of equation (5) can be brought in such a form. It seems that in this case, $C(r,\psi)$ depends on $r$ and on the upper bound of the Renyi entropy, also the dimension of the on-site Hilbert spaces. In particular it should not depend on $D$.  But i am stressing that this part i am not very sure about.

However, if this is indeed true, i can do the following:

$$ | \text{Tr}(\rho_L^2) - \text{Tr}(\rho_{L+1}^2)| \leq \\
\leq | \text{Tr}(\rho_L^2) - \text{Tr}(\rho_{L,D}^2)| + | \text{Tr}(\rho_{L+1}^2) - \text{Tr}(\rho_{L+1,D}^2)| +| \text{Tr}(\rho_{L,D}^2) - \text{Tr}(\rho_{L+1,D}^2)| \leq \\
\leq \| \rho_L - \rho_{L,D}\|_2 + \| \rho_L - \rho_{L,D}\|_2 + | \text{Tr}(\rho_{L,D}^2) - \text{Tr}(\rho_{L+1,D}^2)|$$

Now for the first two terms i use $(2)$ and for the last term i use (1):

$$ | \text{Tr}(\rho_L^2) - \text{Tr}(\rho_{L+1}^2)| \leq  2 C(r,\psi)(L+1)^2 D^{-r} + 2 D e^{-L/\xi_D}  \ .$$

Now assume that the state $\psi$ has correlation length $\xi$. Then pick some $\zeta > \xi$, and now let $D$ grow with $L$ in the following way:

$$ D(L) = e^{L/\zeta} \ . $$

Since $\psi_D$ converges to $\psi$ for $D\rightarrow \infty$, the correlation length $\xi_D$ has to converge to $\xi$. Hence there is only a finite number of instances of $L$ s.t. $1/\xi_{D(L)} - 1/\zeta < 0$. Thus, we can find some constants $C',\zeta'$ s.t.

$$  | \text{Tr}(\rho_L^2) - \text{Tr}(\rho_{L+1}^2)| \leq C' e^{-L/\zeta'} $$

Hence the limit (which will be denoted by $k$) exists and

$$   | \text{Tr}(\rho_L^2) - k| \leq C'' e^{-L/\zeta'} $$

for some additional constant $C''$.

So this is how far i got; i am not sure whether equation (2) holds. Note that unless the bound on the right hand side does not grow exponentially with $L$, the argument still works, though.

Comment: In https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0701055, Hastings gives an example for an MPS where the entanglement is exponentially larger than the correlation length.  Whether this also implies a counterexample to your point 3, I don't know.  (I would however suspect yes.  In fact, I suspect that there are correlation length $0$ MPS where the entropy has a finite length scale.)

Comment: Update: Isn't your point 3 a triviality?  Basically, isn't this just rephrasing the definition of the limit in terms of f(|X|)?  As long as you don't talk about convergence rates, I don't see what your (ultimate) question is

Comment: My question is about convergence rates... Saying that a certain quantity converges to another obviously implies that their difference decays, but i was wondering what can be said about the speed of this convergence. I mean i want to know the form of f independently from the left hand side. I will look into the Hastings example, thanks!

Comment: Well, the way you state it in point 3 exactly does **not** ask about convergence rates!  If it were, f(x) had to be independent of the **state** (that it is indep. of the representation is obvious).

Comment: ... the way it is currently put it is unclear what you are after, since f(x) will have to depend on sth. (e.g. the correlation length etc.) -- what do you have in mind, what would, and what wouldn't, make you happy?

Comment: Other than that, https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.5140 might be of interest if you care about the interpretation of spectra of transfer matrices.

Comment: I added a calculation to demonstrate what i would be interested in.

Comment: I think it might help if you say what you are ultimately interested in (I guess you want this convergence for sth else). --- BTW, is there a reason why you care about the convergence of tr(rho^2), and not its logarithm?

Comment: So i am not yet sure what is the precise statement i'm after, but i would like to take limits of matrix product states and still retain some control about the second entanglement entropy. Of course if i take limits in the Hilbert space, i will not get any interesting property, but i could for example use a notion of convergence where the correlation length has to remain finite. (to give a more specialized context: i am doing some calculations with partial transposes and matrix product states, and to show that tr(rho^2) remains always finite seems to be important there.)

Comment: But do you care about finiteness or about convergence rates?  That's two quite different things.  You could try to post one of the concrete problems, like the one with the partial transpose.

Comment: So originally i thought it to be important to have some information on convergence rates, but i no longer believe this to be the case. I will try to formulate a better question.

Comment: i made a new question  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/471967/partial-transpose-in-gapped-time-reversal-symmetric-spin-chains .