# Partial Transpose in Gapped Time-reversal Symmetric Spin Chains

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-entanglement, topological-phase, spin-chains, tensor-network

Suppose you have a one-dimensional quantum spin system with on-site Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{S}$. Suppose there is an anti-unitary, anti-linear operator $C$ on $\mathcal{S}$ inducing an anti-linear, anti-unitary operator $C_X$ on any $\mathcal{H}_{X} := \bigotimes_{x \in X} \mathcal{S}$.

In this situation one can define a partial transpose; namely consider disjoint subsets $X_1,X_2 \subset \mathbb{Z}$ and let $A = A_1 \otimes A_2$ be a operator on $\mathcal{H}_{X_1} \otimes \mathcal{H}_{X_2}$. Then define the partial transpose to be the $\mathbb{C}$-linear extension of

$$ (A_1 \otimes A_2)^{T_1} = (C_{X_1} A_1^* C_{X_1}) \otimes A_2  \ .$$

Assume $\Omega$ is a injective translation invariant matrix product state symmetric under $C_{\mathbb{Z}}$. Consider two adjacent disjoint intervals $X_1,X_2$ and $X = X_1 \cup X_2$ and let $L = \min(|X_1|,|X_2|)$. Then

$$ Z:= \lim_{L \rightarrow \infty} \text{Tr}(\rho_X^{T_1} \rho_X) = \pm \lim_{L \rightarrow \infty} \text{Tr}(\rho_X^2)^{\frac{3}{2}} \ . $$

Here, if $\mathcal{C}$ implements $C$ on the auxiliary space, the sign is $+1$ if $\mathcal{C}$ is a real structure and $-1$ if $\mathcal{C}$ is quaternionic.

1) Are some references to this? Is this known? I know that people have calculated some things with partial transposes in critical systems, but for gapped systems? There is of course the work by [Shinsei Ryu et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.01886), but they work with fermionic systems (which is my goal as well) and they don't seem to give proofs.

EDIT: I since have found a couple of references. The earliest one seems to be [Pollman and Turner](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.0704.pdf) who did the above calculation. It also shows up in this [more comprehensive account by Ryu et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.06504.pdf).

I want to conclude: since MPS states are dense in Hilbert space, the above then holds for all $C$-invariant states.

2) In going from the statement about MPS to general states: what could go wrong? For example, there is the problem of frustration, which i think plays no role here because i am considering pure states in the thermodynamic limit.

EDIT: As was shown by [Fannes et al](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002212368471041X), the translation invariant pure states are $w*$-dense in the set of all translation invariant states. It seems that this notion of convergence will not be tight enough, at least so far i could only check that $Z$ is a continuous on Hilbert space with its norm given by the inner product. I would expect a stronger convergence to hold for exponentially clustering states.

Comment: I don't know any references on this, but in 1D you could presumably use a Jordan-Wigner transformation and use the fermionic results. By the way, it'd be good if you'd add link to Ryu's work in the post.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that a special case would be the "normal" partial transpose, with a wavefunction with real coefficients?

Comment: A real structure is just a way to formalize what is meant when we say a wave function has real coefficients, so yes.

Comment: I did it on the AKLT state... for MPS i am also pretty confident because one can do the calculation (its just a bit lengthy). I am more wondering what could go wrong in going from a statement about MPS to a statement about all states.

Comment: I have a calculation for MPS, and i want to conclude from there a statement about all pure translation invariant exponentially clustering $C$-symmetric ground states by taking limits.

Comment: "since MPS states are dense" -- What *precisely* do you mean by that? (Ordering of limits!  Dense in *what*?)

Comment: Interesting equation. Do you know why homogeneity is not preserved in your equation?

Comment: @lcv Why *should* homogeneity be preserved in the first place?

Comment: Hi @NorbertSchuch, well, I haven't said it _should_ be preserved. But in general is a very strong property, (like inequalities are preserved taking limit). It is quite possible that it is simply hidden, i.e. the RHS could have a factor $1/\mathrm{Tr} (\rho_X )$

Comment: @lcv Basically, yes, there is a normalization "hidden".  In terms of the entanglement spectrum $\Lambda$ (of the half-chain), the LHS is $\mathrm{tr}(\Lambda^2)^3$ and the trace in the RHS is $\mathrm{tr}(\Lambda^2)^2\,\mathrm{tr}(\Lambda)^2$, which is homogeneous in $\Lambda$ (and thus in the state). Normalization implies $\mathrm{tr}\Lambda=1$, which then yields the relation above between the two traces.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, great thanks! All is good under the sun. (The issue it's not entirely 'accademic'. We may decide to normalize probabilities to $\lambda$. Indeed in some communities they pick $\lambda=100$). Have a good day